# displaying an array of floats as image via opencv

Tags: c++, arrays, image, opencv

I'm working with c++ on a float array. I would like to display this array as an image via opencv.

this is the relevantpart of the code(`dataRSLT_f_unwrapped` is my data array):

```
CvMat MatResult;
cvInitMatHeader(&MatResult, Ny, Nx, CV_32FC1, dataRSLT_f_unwrapped);
cvNormalize(&MatResult, imgRSLT, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX);
cvShowImage( "Example2", imgRSLT );
```

it appears that the `cvNormalize` function creates the followng error when trying to run:

`"Unhandled exception at at 0x776CC42D in FinalProj3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0041F3A4."`

Comment: not sure where your error comes from, but your normalization will be wrong anyways. OpenCV will display float values the way that 0=black to 1=white (because it multiplies by 255 before rendering).

Comment: If you are working in C++, why are you using functions of C? Use `cv::Mat`, `cvInitMatHeader` I do not know, use `cv::normalize` and `cv::imshow`... Also see `cv::imdecode`